# Is there a good explanation for the forms 大きな, 小さな and 多くの?

Tags: etymology, classical-japanese, old-japanese

Is there a good historical/etymological explanation why 大きい and 小さい can take the な ending in attributive position?

Also, is there a good historic/etymological explanation why 多い in attributive use turns into 多くの-?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjectives functioning both as イ- and ナ-adjective](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6675/adjectives-functioning-both-as-%e3%82%a4-and-%e3%83%8a-adjective)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

大きな is the 連体形 (attributive form) of an old na-adjective おおきなり, and only the attributive form is used in the present day. 小さな, おかしな are also the same thing. They are analyzed as pre-noun adjectivals.

The attribute form of 多い is 多い, but it alone isn't commonly used such as 多い車. However 多い with a modifier can be used as the attribute form such as 外国人の多い学校. 多く is a noun, so when it modifies a noun, の is needed after a noun such as お菓子の家.

Comment: Note that there are other ～く adverbial forms that have lexicalized as nouns: 近【ちか】くand 遠【とお】く are the examples that jump immediately to mind, and there may be others that escape me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer your first question.
If you think of it from a grammatical perspective,

> 大きい

is used in sentences such as

> 大きいです。(It is large.) or 大きく書きます。(I will write it large.)

the word 大きい can be used at the end of the sentence or be connected to a verb.

On the other hand, 大きな can only be used to be connected to a Noun.

There is another difference that exists. The previous example does not quite explain the difference, so this might help in that perspective. I will use these two sentences to compare.

> 大きい木 (Large Tree) and 大きな木 (Large Tree)

The Japanese dictionary gives examples of 大きな.

> 大きな政府 (Large Government)
>
> 大きな影響を与える (Give a large effect)
>
> 大きな意味がある (t has a big meaning.)

If you look at the 大きい part of the dictionary, you will get:

> 大きい服 (Large clothes)
>
> 大きい体 (Large body)
>
> 大きい字 (Large words)

It looks like most Japanese use 大きな with more abstract concepts, and 大きい with more objective or literal concepts.

I could not find much information about the second question, but here is a grammatical explanation, if it helps.

多い and 多くの, is a special case adjective since it cannot be used before the noun it describes.
This sentence would not work:

> 多い 人(ひと[people])　が　います。

Instead, you can use it after the noun.

> 人が　多い　です。

So if you want to say many+noun in Japanese you use 多くの.
多くの人

I hope this helps. Please tell me if I can help by clarifying anything.

---

cr:

https://www.nihongo-c.co.jp/blog/blog-entry-100.html

https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/17661

Comment: 質問は、Is there a good **historical/etymological** explanation why... て。。。

Comment: 見落としてました。迷惑おかけいたしました。直させていただきます！